# customizing positional command arguments with yargs

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, yargs

I am trying to use yargs for a command line application and I have run into a problem with my positional arguments.

I have:

```
require('yargs')
    .command(
        'my-command <value>',
        'This command does someting'
        (y) => {
            return y
                .option('my-option', {
                    describe: "Some option",
                    demandOption: true
                })
         }
         (args) => {
             //execute my command here
         }
    )
    .help()
    .completion()
    .argv
```

This allows me to call:

```
my-program my-command my-value --my-option=hello!
```

And the args.value now contains "my-value".

So far so good. The problem however is that the 'value' argument does not show up in the help text. I would also like to restrict the value argument further, basically add a choices array to it. But I can only find how to do this using the .option() function which produces a -- flag. Such as for --my-option.

Is it possible to customize a positional argument in the same way as customizing a -- option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not supported.
https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/541

And the issue is closed so likely will not be implemented any time soon.